# Writing Data to Internal File - ContextWrapper NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a file for internal storage, and I'm running into a problem when the data is written. I know that it retrieves the right data when it's called (I used a Logcat tag to check that it was), but as soon as it tries to open the FileOutputStream, it says that there is a NullPointerException on the second line:

```
static ContextWrapper wrap = new ContextWrapper(context);
FileOutputStream gamesave = wrap.openFileOutput (FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
gamesave.write(DATA.getBytes());
gamesave.close();
```

I've looked at other questions and I can't figure out why the NullPointerException is there, it seems to be following the right procedure.

Comment: _where_ is the NPE? On which line

Comment: btw, `static`.. ? Is this real code?

Comment: The second line. Maybe I shouldn't be instantiating the ContextWrapper, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong Context in your `context` var (i.e. ApplicationContext). Try using the context directly - without the Wrapper.

Comment: The problem is that it isn't an activity! Is that the only way to make this work?

Comment: Where do you get the context from?

Comment: I can create a constructor for the class, but the problem might be coming from the fact that I'm creating multiple instances of the class in other classes, since there are multiple places that borrow methods from it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a ContextWrapper?  There is no reason to do that.  Just use the Context you have at hand -- the Activity if you are an Activity, or one passed in to your code if not.

Note that it is perfectly fine to use the Application as a Context for this.